# Extract specific entries from blastx output file, write to new file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, biopython, blast

I have created a script that successfully searches for keywords (specified by user) within a Blastx output file in XML format. Now, I need to write those records (query, hit, score, evalue, etc) that contain the keyword in the alignment title to a new file.

I have created separate lists for each of the query titles, hit title, e-value and alignment lengths but cannot seem to write them to a new file.

- Problem #1: what if Python errors, and one of the lists is missing a value...? Then all the other lists will be giving wrong information in reference to the query ("line slippage", if you will...).
- Problem #2: even if Python doesn't error, and all the lists are the same length, how can I write them to a file so that the first item in each list is associated with each other (and thus, item #10 from each list is also associated?) Should I create a dictionary instead?
- Problem#3: dictionaries have only a single value for a key, what if my query has several different hits? Not sure if it will be overwritten or skipped, or if it will just error. Any suggestions? My current script:

  ```
  from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
  from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
  import re

  #obtain full path to blast output file (*.xml)
  outfile = input("Full path to Blast output file (XML format only): ")

  #obtain string to search for
  search_string = input("String to search for: ")

  #open the output file
  result_handle = open(outfile)

  #parse the blast record
  blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)

  #initialize lists
  query_list=[]
  hit_list=[]
  expect_list=[]
  length_list=[]

  #create 'for loop' that loops through each HIGH SCORING PAIR in each ALIGNMENT from each RECORD
  for record in blast_records:
          for alignment in record.alignments:     #for description in record.descriptions???
                  for hsp in alignment.hsps:      #for title in description.title???

                          #search for designated string
                          search = re.search(search_string, alignment.title)

                          #if search comes up with nothing, end
                          if search is None:
                                  print ("Search string not found.")
                                  break

                          #if search comes up with something, add it to a list of entries that match search string
                          else:

                                  #option to include an 'exception' (if it finds keyword then DOES NOT add that entry to list)
                                  if search is "trichomonas" or "entamoeba" or "arabidopsis":
                                          print ("found exception.")
                                          break
                                  else:

                                          query_list.append(record.query)
                                          hit_list.append(alignment.title)
                                          expect_list.append(expect_val)
                                          length_list.append(length)

                                          #explicitly convert 'variables' ['int' object or 'float'] to strings
                                          length = str(alignment.length)
                                          expect_val = str(hsp.expect)

                                          #print ("\nquery name: " + record.query)
                                          #print ("alignment title: " + alignment.title)
                                          #print ("alignment length: " + length)
                                          #print ("expect value: " + expect_val)
                                          #print ("\n***Alignment***\n")
                                          #print (hsp.query)
                                          #print (hsp.match)
                                          #print (hsp.sbjct + "\n\n")


                                          if query_len is not hit_len is not expect_len is not length_len:
                                                  print ("list lengths don't match!")
                                                  break
                                          else:

                                                  qrylen = len(query_list)
                                                  query_len = str(qrylen)
                                                  hitlen = len(hit_list)
                                                  hit_len = str(hitlen)
                                                  expectlen = len(expect_list)
                                                  expect_len = str(expectlen)
                                                  lengthlen = len(length_list)
                                                  length_len = str(lengthlen)
                                                  outpath = str(outfile)

                                                  #create new file
                                                  outfile = open("__Blast_Parse_Search.txt", "w")
                                                  outfile.write("File contains entries from [" + outpath + "] that contain [" + search_string + "]")
                                                  outfile.close

                                                  #write list to file
                                                  i = 0
                                                  list_len = int(query_len)
                                                  for i in range(0, list_len):

                                                          #append new file
                                                          outfile = open("__Blast_Parse_Search.txt", "a")
                                                          outfile.writelines(query_list + hit_list + expect_list + length_list)
                                                          i = i + 1

                                                  #write to disk, close file
                                                  outfile.flush()
                                                  outfile.close

  print ("query list length " + query_len)
  print ("hit list length " + hit_len)
  print ("expect list length " + expect_len)
  print ("length list length " + length_len + "\n\n")
  print ("first record: " + query_list[0] + " " + hit_list[0] + " " + expect_list[0] + " " + length_list[0])
  print ("last record: " + query_list[-1] + " " + hit_list[-1] + " " + expect_list[-1] + " " + length_list[-1])
  print ("\nFinished.\n")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you could use a default value for the line slippage thing like:

```
try:
  x(list)
except exception:
  append_default_value(list)
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

or use tuples for dictionary keys like `(0,1,1)` and use the get method for your default value.

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

If you need to maintain data structures in your output files you might try using shelve:

or you could append some type of reference after each record and give each record a unique id for example '`#32{somekey:value}#21#22#44#`'

again you can have multiple keys using a tuple.

I don't know if that helps, you might clarify exactly what parts of your code you have trouble with. Like `x()` gives me output `y` but I expect `z`.